# listview adapter doesnt want to set text

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, settext

ok I am trying to do simple listview filling from array with adapter so I have:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
String[] dish = {"soup", "rice", "grecha", "potato"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lunch);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); 
    setContentView(R.layout.lunch);
    ListView lunchLV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lunchLV);
    cafeAdapter ca = new cafeAdapter();
    lunchLV.setAdapter(ca);

}


public class cafeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dish.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
       view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(dish[i]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

}

I also have list.xml file and lunch.xml file

For some weird reasons title.setText(dish[i]); produces an error and makes my program crash.
I have element with id "title in my xml file but anyways java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference.

Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have all in the same file.. dish string just inside the mainactivity. when I was trying to just setText("hello") I had the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
```

Instead:

```
 TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
```